# R nls singular gradient starting value

Tags: r, nls

I am having a problem while fitting a fucntion via nls

This is the Data:

```
size<-c(0.0020,0.0063,0.0200,0.0630,0.1250,0.2000,0.6300,2.0000)
cum<-c(6.4,7.1,7.6,37.5,83.0,94.5,99.9,100.0)
```

I want to fit Gompertz model to it. Therefor i tried:

```
start<-c(alpha =100, beta = 10, k = 0.03)
fit<-nls(cum~ alpha*exp(-beta*exp(-k*size)),start=start)
```

> The Error says: Singulat gradient.

Some post suggest to choose better starting values.

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: I'd recommend [looking at the Wikipedia page for the Gompertz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function) and making some graphs on top of your data to try to get things (a) in the right direction and (b) close to the right order of magnitude (say, not off by more than 10 or 20 times). Wikipedia has graphs varying 1 coefficient at a time, which should help you get close.

Answer (score 2):

The starting values are too far away from the optimal ones.  First take logs of both sides in which case there is only one non-linear parameter, `k`. Only that needs a starting value if we use the `plinear` algorithm.  Using `k` from that fit as the `k` starting value refit using original formula.

```
fit.log <- nls(log(cum) ~ cbind(1, exp(-k*size)), alg = "plinear", start = c(k = 0.03))

start <- list(alpha = 100, beta = 10, k = coef(fit.log)[["k"]])
fit <- nls(cum ~ alpha*exp(-beta*exp(-k*size)), start = start)
fit
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: cum ~ alpha * exp(-beta * exp(-k * size))
   data: parent.frame()
  alpha    beta       k 
100.116   3.734  22.340 
 residual sum-of-squares: 45.87

Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.351e-06
```

We can show the fit on a graph

```
plot(cum ~ size, pch = 20)
lines(fitted(fit) ~ size, col = "red")
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]